# Intellij IDEA - how to link test class with @link or @see in JavaDoc; does not prompt

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I want to link with `@link` or `@see` in Javadoc some test class, but Intellij IDEA  does not prompt/import the right class as I type. In contrast, when I link some source class, it does prompt and auto-complete the class/method/property name.

Why? How to link them?

Comment: Do you mean the class from the *test source* is not auto-completed in your source class? It is expected since your source class does not have the dependency on your test class - so it is not "visible" to it. If situation is different please add more information: where the class is located in project which is not auto-completed. Provide code example explaining what is not working as expected.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I mean that test classes are not auto-completed, somehow "not on the classpath". I understand it as `main` and `test` is on the same level.  Consider to make it an answer? So if I want to link to some tests for demonstrative usage, how can I do that?